# Clarify array of structs pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a generic struct declared and an array of these structs as given below:

```
struct A
{
    int x,y,z;
    char a,b,c;
};

struct A *str_arr[5];
```

From my understanding `str_arr` is a pointer to a block of memory which stores pointers to the 5 structs in sequential order and therefore these pointers can be accessed via pointer arithmetic or array indexing as:

```
struct A *str_a = str_arr[1];                    // points to 2nd struct?
struct A *str_b = str_arr + 2*sizeof(struct A*); // points to 3rd struct?
```

However, these 5 structs might not be in sequential memory?

```
printf("%p\n", str_arr);              // prints memory location of start of str_arr pointers?
printf("%p\n", str_arr[1])            // prints memory location of 2nd struct?
printf("%d\n" str_arr == &str_arr[0]) // prints 1?
```

I would just like clarification that my understanding is correct with all of the points I have raised.

Comment: `str_arr` is array of pointer to `struct A` (five pointer to `struct A`).

Comment: Just like the integers in `int a[42]` do not have to be in sequential order. They are whatever you put in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All is correct except one:

```
struct A **str_b = str_arr + 2 /* *sizeof(struct A*) */;
/*       ^^                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
/* Not need to multiply with size. Dereference with * if your type is struct A * */
```

or

```
struct A *str_b = *(str_arr + 2);
```

You give the offset in terms of number of elements and not the size in bytes.

`str_arr + 2*sizeof(struct A*)` is equivalent to `&str_arr[2*sizeof(struct A*)]`

```
             +0  +1  +2  +3  +4
           +---+---+---+---+---+
           | A | B | C | D | E |
           +---+---+---+---+---+
str_arr    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
&str_arr[0]^^^^   
str_arr[1] = B
```

- str_arr is the address of array start
- str_arr[1] is the contents at offset `+1` i.e. B which is an address pointing to object of type `struct A`.
- `str_arr == &str_arr[0]` are same address with different type

As suggested by @Gopi, last point can be proven by printing the following:

1. sizeof str_arr v/s &str_arr[0]
2. Following address, `&str_arr + 1` v/s `str_arr + 1`

Comment: Yes, it does, only with the different type. That means address generated from `&str_arr` and `str_arr + 0`  are same but addresses generated from expressions `&str_arr + 1` and `str_arr + 1` are different

Comment: Yeah I know I meant that also can be added to the answer

Comment: @Gopi Thanks for the input. I thought it is implied by the figure. Length of `^^`^is different for `str_arr` and `&str_arr[0]`. But still feel free to edit the answer if you can add more helpful or easier to read info for OP. I will try to add your suggestion.